# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after dockerizing Vuejs app

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to dockerize my frontend and I've followed this tutorial https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'frontend' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /frontend

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

When I go to `localhost:8000` it says the site cannot be reached and `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: How are you running your container? you need to map container port to host port `docker run -p 8080:8080 myimage`

Comment: This was the build `docker build -t vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app .` and this is how I started the container `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm --name dockerize-vuejs-app-1 vuejs-cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app`

Comment: Is your server actually running? Can you go into the container `docker exec -it container_id sh` and then `curl 127.0.0.1:8080`. You're running off the alpine image so you may need to install curl

Comment: Am I supposed to do this in a different window? I tried doing this in a different terminal and have the container running in the background, but I get this `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: Then I tried this `eval $(docker-machine env default)` but this was requesting a password and I didn't know what password it's requesting for, I used the one that I would use to login to my laptop but that didn't work

Comment: hmm, looks like you're using the old docker which runs containers inside a virtualbox vm. `localhost` will not work. You need to use your `docker-machine` ip address

Comment: you can get the ip by running `docker-machine ip`

Comment: After I get the ip address what do I do, do I replace that with 8000 in `EXPOSE`?

Comment: no just visit it in your browser. http://<docker-machine-ip>:8080 I really recommend learning image vs containers and how it all works together to solidify your fundamentals in this area https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: This works tysm!

Comment: How can I use new docker instead of running containers inside a virutalbox VM?

Comment: uninstall your current docker and download it again from https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/

Comment: Why do you enter `localhost:8000` when you've exposed port number **8080**? You've mentioned in comments you run it by `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 ...`. Are you sure you've entered the correct port number?

Comment: I enter it in my browser and it's what the guide I linked in my post told me to go to. This issue has been resolved